# Autograder script - reading keyboard inputs from textfile

Tags: python, c, automation, automated-tests

I need to score my students c programming homeworks. I want to write an autograder script which automatically score the homeworks. I plan to write this script in python language.

My question is, in the homework, in some parts students get some input from keyboard with **scanf**, how can i handle this problem if I try to write an autograder?  Is there any way to read from text file when the **scanf** line runs in homework ?

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `subprocess` module in Python to spawn other programs, retrieve their output and feed them arbitrary input. The relevant pieces will most likely be the `Popen.communicate()` method and/or the `.stdin` and `.stdout` file objects; ensure when you do this that you passed `PIPE` as the argument to the `stdin` and `stdout` keywords on creation.